# Is there a standard way to compress an .htaccess deny list

Tags: .htaccess

If I have a long list of CIDR ranges to block

`deny from 107.154.228.0/24
deny from 108.166.232.0/21
deny from 108.166.240.0/21
deny from 108.171.143.0/24
...`

Is there a utility I should use to compress this to

`deny from 107.154.228.0/24 108.166.232.0/21 108.166.240.0/21 108.171.143.0/24 ...`

or should I just write a shell script to do this?  I didn't want to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? That alternate form is much harder to maintain...

Comment: My thinking was to make it easier to refresh since these lists change frequently.  I'd just grab the latest list, format it as above to reduce the number of lines, and replace the existing entries.